# ExecuteScalar SQL Server no almacena un entero? C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Buenas tardes, quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal porque al guardar los datos a través de un insert, se me guarda la primary key con un valor muy grande (al parecer es decimal) la tabla tiene la primary key como identity por lo que debiese guardarse 1,2,3....etc.

pero al hacer el insert en la primary se guarda 1004,1005,1006 cada registro nuevo insertado.. y deseo ocupar esta id generada en otra tabla al mismo tiempo por lo que no quiero tener problemas con ese valor, prefiero que se guarde desde el 1 en adelante, este es mi código:

```
public static bool crearPlanificacion(Planificacion recibo)
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO ActividadPlanificada (idActividadGenerica, idSucursalEmpresa,anio, mes,descripcionActividadPlanificada) VALUES" +
        "(@idActividadGenerica,@idSucursalEmpresa,@anio, @mes,@descripcionActividadPlanificada);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); ";

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conexionString);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        //TANTAS VECES COMO idActividadGenerica VENGAN DESDE EL CLIENTE

            //Tabla ActividadPlanificada
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idActividadGenerica", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = recibo.idActividadGenerica; //desde array json
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idSucursalEmpresa", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = recibo.idSucursalEmpresa;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@anio", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = recibo.anio;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mes", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = recibo.mes;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@descripcionActividadPlanificada", SqlDbType.Text)).Value = recibo.descripcionActividadPlanificada;

            //Ejecutamos la consulta y obtenemos la id de la actividadPlanificada para insertarla en las otras tablas
            Int32 pkActividadPlanificada = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

            //deseo ocupar esta variable para insertarla en otra tabla al mismo tiempo "pkActividadPlanificada"


        connection.Close();                
        return true;                
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: En realidad no tiene mucha importancia eso. Puedes usar los valores que recibes sin ningún problema. No estás haciendo mal. De hecho tu código no tiene nada que ver con lo que está pasando. Es SQL Server que decide qué valor te devuelve.

Comment: @sstan muchas gracias por responder, y puedo hacer algo en el código si es que quiero que se empiece a almacenar con las id desde el 1 en adelante? siento raro que empieze desde el 1001 en adelante siendo que  la tabla esta recien creada :/

Comment: En el código no. En la base de datos, puedes hacer un RESEED, si quieres hacer una búsqueda al respecto. Pero te recomiendo que te quites ese miedo, porque hay muchas razones que pueden llevar a que las columnas IDENTITY no tengan una secuencia perfecta de ids, y eso es normal.

Comment: Perfecto @sstan muchas gracias por tu rápida ayuda! saludos :)

Comment: El Inconveniente es el SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); este te devuelve el valor que se inserta al final y te lo inserta eso es lo que pasa, si quieres que se guarde con un entero mayor que 1 debes de indicarlo con identity